# Where to put SQL queries that join on multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, tablemodel

I am using an MVC framework and have a `photo` SQL table and an `album` SQL table. Queries for the `photo` table go in the `photoTableModel` class, and queries for `album` table go in the `albumTableModel` class.

Where do I put queries that use both tables?

For example, the following query uses both tables. Do I place the query in the `photoTableModel`, `albumTableModel`, a new table model altogether, or maybe even a service?

```
SELECT `photo`.`id`
     , `photo`.`name`
  FROM `photo`
  JOIN `album`
    ON `album`.`album_id` = `photo`.`album_id`
   AND `album`.`album_id` = 1
     ;
```

Comment: This is using for whom admin or user if admin then in admin model else user model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center of the architecture is models, not tables.  Semantically, which model is being described or operated on here?

This *appears* to be retrieving a list of photos, with some album information included in the elements of that list.  So I suspect that this is related to the `Photo` logical model.  So wherever you put this in your architecture and framework, it should be semantically related to that model.

How your *framework* defines things is up to that framework, so I really can't be more specific.  Different frameworks do different things in different ways.  In general, however, in the MVC pattern you want to build your logic and architecture around the models.  And what you get from this query is a list of photos (with some extra information), so it's related to the Photo model.

Models *can* be direct one-to-one representations of tables.  But they don't *need* to be.  It looks like you're artificially limiting your models to be exactly that, which has led to this issue.  Maybe you extend the `Photo` model concept to include album information?  Maybe you create a DTO that's a hybrid of the two?  Maybe you add an `Album` property to your `Photo` model?  There are many ways to go about organizing models.  The point is to keep the *semantics* of those models clear.  Models represent *domain concepts* (like `Photo`), not database tables (like `photoTableModel`).  The database tables simply persist the model information to be re-constructed later.  As such, the database is an *edge* concern for the domain, not a *central* one.

Comment: Beautifully worded, like a work of art. Thank you so much.